# formula to generate array with variables such as =B1/B2, etc

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

How does one generate an array whose elements are cell values or math operation of cell values? For example, how does one generate an array of {0,1,A1,B1}) or {8,3,A1/B1,A1*B1} or {0,1,A1/B1-2, A1*B1+3}?

I have not found anything on the net regarding this topic.

Comment: You just want to display the array in { a,b,c,d } format or you want to do operations on them? If operations, what operations.. any examples ?

Comment: It'll be used in a LOOKUP function as the second argument, LOOKUP(xxx,{0,1,A1,B1},yyy), something like that.

Comment: Directly, I'm not sure. Indirectly, put 8 in C1, 3 in C2, `=A1`, in C3, `=B1` in C4 , then use C1:C4 as the array range. (I'll use this method if it was up to me)

Comment: That's not the answer I'm looking for but that might be the only answer.